# PDF for zero point of random function

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, random-walk, stochastic-integrals

Let us suppose a complex random function $\displaystyle \Psi (\mathbf{x})$ and its complex conjugate $\displaystyle \Psi ^{*}(\mathbf{x})$. We assume that these functions possess gaussian statistics, so that mean value of some functional $\displaystyle f\left[ \Psi ,\Psi ^{*}\right]$ shall be calculated as
\begin{equation*}
\langle f\rangle =\dfrac{\int D\Psi ^{*} D\Psi \ f\left[ \Psi ,\Psi ^{*}\right] \ \exp\left[ -\int \mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{x} \ \Psi ^{*}\hat{K} \Psi \right]}{\int D\Psi ^{*} D\Psi \ \exp\left[ -\int \mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{x} \ \Psi ^{*}\hat{K} \Psi \right]}
\end{equation*}
Here $\hat{K}$ is some differential operator.

**The question**: if I know for certain, that for the function $\displaystyle \Psi (\mathbf{x})$ there is such a point $\displaystyle \mathbf{y}$, that $\displaystyle \Psi (\mathbf{y}) =0$, how can I calculate a probability distibustion function for  $\displaystyle \mathbf{y}$? Shall it be

\begin{equation*}
P(\mathbf{y}) =\langle \delta ( \Re \Psi (\mathbf{y})) \cdotp \delta ( \Im \Psi (\mathbf{y})) \rangle 
\end{equation*}
or something else?

Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: What's $D$? ${}{}$

Comment: Also is $\Psi$ random, or does it determine a probability distribution on $\mathbf{x}$ by the measure $A \mapsto \frac{\int_A D \Psi^* D \Psi \exp[\dots] \, d \mathbf{x}}{\int_\Omega D \Psi^* D \Psi \exp[\dots] \, d \mathbf{x}}$ where $\Omega$ is the whole domain (presumably $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

Comment: @Ian $D$ is a symbol, which denotes path integral measure. It doesn't exist in a rigorous way, the well-defined object here is so called Wiener measure, which is $D\Psi^* D\Psi \exp(-\Psi^* \hat{K} \Psi)$. $\Psi(\mathbf{x})$ is random itself, it can be understood as infinite-dimensional random vector, in a way as any function $f(x)$ can be thought as infinite-dimensional vector.

Comment: Alright, that's not how mathematicians write these things (in terms of both symbols and the natural language part) but I understand.

Comment: That being said, your question is now ill-posed unless you know for certain that the zero is *unique*. Otherwise you need some scheme for how to select a zero from a given $\Psi$, which will affect the distribution of the zero.

Comment: Assuming the zero is actually unique, think through it like this. Start with the case where the set of possible zeros is just finite. Then to get a PMF you want the average of a functional that sends a $\Psi$ with $\Psi(\mathbf{y})=0$ to $1$ and sends any other $\Psi$ to zero. Next, consider asking for the probability that the zero is in some set $A \subset \mathbb{C}$. Then again you want to integrate a functional that sends a $\Psi$ such that $\Psi(\mathbf{y})=0$ for some $\mathbf{y} \in A$ to $1$ and sends any other $\Psi$ to zero.

Comment: Now if you look for a density then you divide the above by $\mathrm{vol}(A)$ and contract $A$ to a point, which amounts to integrating the aforementioned functional against $\delta(\mathbf{y})$. So your density becomes $f(\mathbf{x})=\int_X \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}) g_{\mathbb{y}}[\Psi] \, d\mathbb{P}(\Psi)$ where $g_{\mathbb{y}}(h)=\begin{cases} 1 & h(\mathbf{y})=0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ and $X$ is your function space. This is kind of similar to what you said but with several substantial differences.

Comment: Where I wrote $\mathbb{C}$ above I should've written $\mathbb{R}^n$. Oh well, not gonna bother fixing it.